# MQL4 multi-timeframe indicator

Tags: trading, mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4

I would like to write out an indicator that can take in input the `int shift` of an assigned timeframe, and turns out a value related to another timeframe.

As an example, I would like to write an MACD indicator over a 100 periods of M15, that can return out its value 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... minutes before the current candle.

Since in the current candle this indicator "changes" its value, tick by tick, I think that should be possible to write out such an indicator, but I can not figure out how to do it.

Comment: **And what have you tried so far?** In older MQL4/MT4-Builds, there were issues with having correct multi-time-frame behaviour inside the MetaTrader Terminal 4 Strategy Tester, so indeed, this is rather a danger zone if trying to design robust programmes for going into [Production].

Comment: I just need to recall the value af an indicator over a time grid which has a resolution lower than that of the current timeframe on which the indicator is calculated.

I.e. i need to ask somethig like _if the MACD over 100 M15 periods were lower than a value 7 minutes ago, than do something_.

For now i recall indicators in my code using iCustom, but it takes in input the `int shift` related to the time frame on which it calculates the specified custom indicator.

Comment: I would like to write a custom indicator so that i can insert it on the charts and see, for example, in the M15 charts, the trend of the MACD indicator calculated over 100 M30 periods

Comment: Sure, the solution is described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to write it in a very simple way:

```
double M1  (int shift) {double val = iCustom(NULL,PERIOD_M1, "my_indicator",100,2.0,30.0,0,shift); return(val);}
double M15 (int shift) {double val = iCustom(NULL,PERIOD_M15,"my_indicator",100,2.0,30.0,0,shift); return(val);}

int s1_15;
double B_M1_M15(int i) {

                          if (i>=0  && i<15 ) s1_15=0;
                     else if (i>=15 && i<30 ) s1_15=1;
                     else if (i>=30 && i<45 ) s1_15=2;
                     else if (i>=45 && i<60 ) s1_15=3;
                     else if (i>=60 && i<75 ) s1_15=4;

                     return NormalizeDouble(MathAbs(M1(i) - M15(s1_15)),Digits);

                     }
```

and so on for every others couples of timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

### MQL4 language principally has tools for this:

However, as noted above, your experimentation will need thorough quant validations, as the earlier Builds did not support this in **[MT4-Strategy Tester]** code-execution environment ( and more recent shifts into *New-*`MQL4.56789` have devastated performance constraints for all **[CustomIndicators]**, the all **[MT4-graph]**-GUI-s together plus the all **[Expert Advisor]**-s use, since all these suddenly share one ( yes, ONE and THE ONLY ) computing thread.

Ok, you have been warned :o)

So,
if indeed keen to equip your **[CustomIndicator]** so as to be independent of the GUI-native-TimeFrame, all your calculations inside such [CustomIndicator]-code must use indirect access-tools to source the PriceDOMAIN data - so never use any `{ Open[] | High[] | Low[] | Close[] }`-TimeSeries data directly, but **only** using **`{ iOpen() | iHigh() | iLow() | iClose() }`**

All these access tools conceptually have a common signature:

```
double  iLow( string   symbol,          // symbol 
              int      timeframe,       // timeframe 
              int      shift            // shift
              );
```

and
if your code
obeys this duty,
your [CustomIndicator]<sup>( **iff** the StrategyTester will not finally spoil the game -- due quant testing will show this )</sup>
**will be working with data from `timeframe` & `shift` of your wish.**

---

### Implementation remarks:

Your [CustomIndicator]-code has to implement a **`"non-GUI-shift"`** independently from the GUI-native-TimeFrame `shift`-counting. See an `iCustom()` signature template for inspiration. The GUI-TimeFrame-`shift` is like moving the line-graph on GUI-screen, i.e. in GUI-native-TimeFrame steps, not taking into account your [CustomIndicator] "internal"-**`"non-GUI-shift"`** values, so your code has to be smarter, so as to process this "internal"-**`"non-GUI-shift"`** during a value generation. If in doubts, during prototyping, validate the proper "mechanics" on `Time[aShiftINTENDED]` vs `iTime( _Symbol, PERIOD_INTENDED, aShiftINTENDED )`

Due to quite a lot of points, where an `iCustom()` call-interface may be a bit misleading, or a revision-change-management error-prone, we got used to use a formal template for each [Custom Indicator] code, helping to maintain referential integrity with a `iCustom()` use in the actual [ExpertAdvisor] code. It might seem a bit dumb, but those, who have spent man*hours in search for a bug in { un- | ill- }-propagated call-interface changes, this may become a life-saver.

We formalise the call-interface in such a way, that this section, maintained in the [CustomIndicator]-code, can always be copied into the [ExpertAdviser] code, so that the `iCustom()` signature-match can be inspected.

```
//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//!!!!
//---- indicator parameters -------------------------------------------------
//                          POSITIONAL ORDINAL-NUMBERED CALLING INTERFACE
//                      all iCustom() calls MUST BE REVISED ON REVISION
//!!!!
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#define          XEMA_CUSTOM_INDICATOR_NAME    "EMA_DEMA_TEMA_XEMA_wShift"   // this.
//--- input parameters ------------------------------------------------------   iCustom( ) CALL INTERFACE
input  int                 nBARs_period      = 8;
extern double              MUL_SIGMA         = 2.5;
sinput ENUM_APPLIED_PRICE  aPriceTYPE        = PRICE_CLOSE;
extern int                 ShiftBARs         = 0;
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
/*      = iCustom( _Symbol,
                   PERIOD_CURRENT, XEMA_CUSTOM_INDICATOR_NAME,  // |-> iCustom INDICATOR NAME
                                   XEMA_nBARs_period,           // |->                         input    nBARs_period
                                   XEMA_MUL_SIGMA,              // |->                         input    MUL_SIGMA
                                   XEMA_PRICE_TYPE,             // |->                         input    aPriceTYPE       from: ENUM_APPLIED_PRICE
                                   XEMA_ShiftBARs,              // |->                         input    ShiftBARs
                                   XEMA_<_VALUE_>_BUFFER_ID,    // |-> line# --------------------------------------------from: { #define'd (e)nums ... }
                                   0                            // |-> [0]-aTimeDOMAIN-offset
                                   );                           //                                                                                      
*/                                                              
#define                            XEMA_Main_AXIS_BUFFER_ID  0  // <----xEMA<maxEMAtoCOMPUTE>[]
#define                            XEMA_UpperBAND_BUFFER_ID  1  
#define                            XEMA_LowerBAND_BUFFER_ID  2  
#define                            XEMA_StdDEV____BUFFER_ID  3  
#define                            XEMA_SimpleEMA_BUFFER_ID  4  // sEMA
#define                            XEMA_DoubleEMA_BUFFER_ID 10  // dEMA
#define                            XEMA_TripleEMA_BUFFER_ID 11  // tEMA

//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
//!!!!
//---- indicator parameters -------------------------------------------------
//                          POSITIONAL ORDINAL-NUMBERED CALLING INTERFACE
//                      all iCustom() calls MUST BE REVISED ON REVISION
//!!!!
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I modified the indicator code (a kama function calulated over close price of bars), substituing `double Close[shift]` with `iClose(NULL , PERIOD_M15 , shift )` so it should alway calculate the value over M15 bar's close price, and i save this indicator as `KMA_M15`.

Now in my EA i call this indicator using the `iCustom` tecnical indicator, in this way `doubleMA100_M15(int shift) { double val = iCustom(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,"KMA_M15",100,2.0,30.0,2.0,2.0,0,1,0,shift);return(val);}`
so this should return the value of KMA_M15 discretized overt a 1 minute grid, shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand how to use this implementation. 

I have to call the indicator in this interface in order to write an iCustom-like indicator that can be call in my EA? 

The indicator i want to use, named kaufman-adaptive-moving-average in my indicator folder, is this pastebin.com/xU1hsYVh .

I tried to recall this indicator in the interface above but it doesen't work https://pastebin.com/TcRRfQGi

Comment: But I also have another question: when I insert a [CustomIndicator], calculated over a fixed timeframe (say M15), on a chart in an inferior time-frame (say M1), I probably see the curve representing such a [CustomIndicator] being smoother than it was in "its" time-frame.
But if I insert that [CustomIndicator] (i.e. calculated over a M15 bar) in a chart of a superior time-frame (say H1), how it behaves the [CustomIndicator] on this chart?

Comment: It does not work this way. Native-GUI time-steps are given. Your iCustom() calls can "escape" from this "hardwired" time-steps, but we use a virtual ( overlay ) graphs, that work in your own control logic ~ be it M1, M3, M5, ... This is the strength to be independent from the native-GUI functionality.

Comment: Ok but sorry i did not understand if the code I've linked in the pastebin.com is the correct way to use this call-interface

Comment: If I copy this code (https://pastebin.com/hKGcHBvi) in my EA, and I use it instead of  the call `double KMA100_M15(int shift) { double val = iCustom(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,"KMA_M15",100,2.0,30.0,2.0,2.0,0,1,0,shift);return(val);}` it seems to work without errors.
But in this way I don't have an Indicator to apply on my charts.

Comment: Immediately once you realise that a **computing** a set of all values ( for a non-native timeframe ) and **plotting** this set of continuously updated values onto the native-GUI ( "across" the native-GUI "hardwired" time steps ) are two different steps, you can implement one after the other and it works like a charm. The "hard-wired" limits of the native-GUI indicator lines were exactly what you tried to escape from, didn't you? So no need to panic here that these lines will not be plot from this ( actually not used ) part of the engine, but by your own multi-time-frame integration code. Voila

Comment: Can't understand yet :( If this is a code that works copied in a EA, how can i write it out as an indicator that can be applied on charts?

Comment: It returns error "event handling function not found" when I use this interface to create an indicator calling the indicator I want to force over the not-GUI-hardwired, but I don't know another way to construct such an indicator.

Comment: It must return this error, as your code, as posted in PasteBin, does not meet the mandatory structure of the [CustomIndicator] type of code. Kindly do not blame others for errors, that were not caused by them, but were cause by your code non compliance with the MQL4 design and syntax rules. Kindly notice **this has nothing to do with either the multi-timeframe solution or the safety measures from the referential integrity provided by the calling interface signatures template.**

Comment: Sure, it hasn't. I thought that calling the [BaseIndicator] in the code in this way `#define      XEMA_CUSTOM_INDICATOR_NAME   "kaufman-adaptive-moving-average"` it was enough meet the mandatory structure of the [CustomIndicator], as it do in EA. It does not, ok.
But I have not yet understood how to write the [CustorIndicator] code so that it has a ` **non-GUI-shift** ` implemented.

Comment: Do you seriously ask me to give you as a free gift [A] the whole pool of know-how **plus** [B] the whole lumpsum of all the design efforts you ask to get **plus** [C] to spend an unlimited time on explaining the whole such code details **plus** [D] to stand ready to also teach you how to understand the MetaTrader Terminal 4 code-execution environment whenever you ask another and another and another question? **With all due respect, it seems, you are not on the right place to ask for this here.** Just review, how many times you have not rewarded all the assistance you have received on questions

Comment: I posted a precise question in an open forum. As in many others forum where where I ask and give.
Talk about reward, then how much money do you want to answer?